# Unable to perform operations over Mongoose result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
    Product
        .findAll()
        .then((products) => {
                  /* Perform operations */
               }
```

The above query returns an array of products. For eg,

```
[ 
  { 
    name: Mobile,
    price: 10000
  },
  { 
    name: Laptop,
    price: 20000
  },
]
```

I need to make some changes to the products array (add new fields based on the values of existing fields, and delete those existing fields). I tried few methods, but none are working:

```
products.forEach((product) => {
    product.[updatedPrice] = updatedPrice;
    delete product[price];
}
```

Array.map() is also not working.

The following works, but I don't know the working behind, and why it is happening. Also, how to delete a field using the same.

```
products.forEach((product) => {
    product.set('updatedPrice', updatedPrice, {strict: false})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing here to note is that in `.then((products)` products object here is not a JSON object but a Mongoose Document object and the set method you are using is defined by the mongoose. You can refer it from here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict

### We can do 2 things:

1. use `lean()` (returns a plain js object)

   Product.findAll().`lean()`.then((products) => {
   /* Perform operations*/
   });

---

2. use `toJSON()` method on products object to convert mongoose object to js object

   Product.findAll().then((products) => {
   products = products.`toJSON()`;
   /* Perform operations*/
   });

**Thanks**